# Почему переменная цикла во время итерации - добавление элементов в массив ведет себя так?

Tags: javascript

уважаемые коллеги, кто может объяснить, почему во время использования данного цикла:

```
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr.push(i);
}
console.log(arr);
Консоль выведет: (9) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

А при использовании вот такой записи:

```
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
}
console.log(arr);
Консоль выведет: (9) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Правильно ли я рассуждаю, что всё дело в том, как работает интерпретатор JS с оператором 'Инкремента/декремента'. Или же тут ещё замешана особенность итерации в JS с данными операторами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего хитрого тут совсем нет. Как и многие функции [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)  возвращает значение. А возвращает она "количество элементов в массиве" после совершения операции. Вот и получается, что после первой вставки там 1, после второй - 2 и т.д.

Comment: Алексей, спасибо большое за ответ! Всё гениальное - просто, а я, чтобы это понять, совсем в дебри полез.